How can I programmatically start page numbering at 0 in an officedown document?
Rendering the R Markdown below returns a docx with two pages and page numbers 1 and 2. I would like the page numbers to be 0 and 1. Is there a way to achieve this programmatically? That is without touching the reference_docx used by the rendering.
---
output: officedown::rdocx_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(officedown) # 0.3.0
```

# A simple header on page 1

\newpage

# A simple header on page 2


Adding latex to question tags, as I feel there must be latex package for this.

One option would be to first render the R Markdown document and then run a VBScript against the output. This approach is adapted from code in the officerWinTools package.
Copy this code chunk to your R Markdown document and run it to render the document and then reset the page numbering as desired.
```{r, eval=FALSE, include=FALSE}
set_pagenumbers_startingnumber <- function(x) {
  
  if(Sys.info()['sysname'] != "Windows"){
    stop('The this function requires Windows operating system.')
  }
  
  vbs_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".vbs")
  
  writeLines(
    c(
      'Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")',
      'objWord.Visible = False',
      'objWord.DisplayAlerts = False',
      sprintf('Set doc = objWord.Documents.Open("%s")', normalizePath(x)),
      'doc.Sections(1).Footers(2).PageNumbers.RestartNumberingAtSection = True',
      'doc.Sections(1).Footers(2).PageNumbers.StartingNumber = 0',
      'doc.Saved = False',
      'doc.Save',
      'doc.Close (TRUE)',
      'objWord.Quit'
    ),
    con = vbs_file,
    sep = "\n",
    useBytes = FALSE
  )
  
  shell(shQuote(vbs_file), "cscript", flag = "//nologo")
  
  invisible(x)
}

rstudioapi::getSourceEditorContext()$path |>
  rmarkdown::render() |>
  set_pagenumbers_startingnumber()
```


Ok interesting thank you! I am working on an Ubuntu 22.04 though so I can't go with it.
